# Output redirection using "require"

Tags: perl, require, io-redirection

In my program `c.pl` I want to use a variable from script `b.pl` which uses package `a.pm`.

I'm using

```
require 'b.pl'
```

This line runs the script `b.pl`, but I need to redirect its output to a text file.

I used to run as

```
perl b.pl > textfile.txt
```

separately, but now I use `require` to share the variable I need to do output redirection a different way.

I tried this

```
require 'b.pl > textfile.txt'
```

but it seems not to be working.

Is there any way to redirect the output without using the redirection operator `>`?

Comment: xy problem and poor design choices.

Comment: @Сухой27 Sir, I have just started learning and practicing perl from a week.

Comment: One options is to use `select` to change the current default handle for output or to reopen `STDOUT` to the file handle of `textfile.txt` before the call to `require`. See [How can close and reopen STDOUT in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6417185/2173773) for more information.

Comment: Regardless of how new you are to Perl, it should be very obvious that `require` imports a module and does not accept shell statements.