# No error or warning for trying to print to an already closed filehandle

Tags: perl, warnings, filehandle

In the following small code, I do not get an error or a warning for lines [09] and [18]. The only warning I get is with line [21]:

```
use strict;                                              # [01]
use warnings FATAL => 'unopened';                        # [02]
                                                         # [03]
open(my $outHandleA, ">outputA.txt") or die ("A: $!\n"); # [04] Opened $outHandleA
print $outHandleA "FILE A\n";                            # [05]
close $outHandleA;                                       # [06] Closed $outHandleA
                                                         # [07]
print $outHandleA;                                       # [08]
print $outHandleA "ABC\n";                               # [09] <---
print $outHandleA;                                       # [10]
print "-----";                                           # [11]
                                                         # [12]
open(OUT, ">outputB.txt") or die ("B: $!\n");            # [13] Opened OUT
print OUT "FILE B\n";                                    # [14]
close OUT;                                               # [15] Closed OUT
                                                         # [16]
print OUT;                                               # [17]
print OUT "DEF\n";                                       # [18] <---
print OUT;                                               # [19]
                                                         # [20]
print DOES_NOT_EXIST_HANDLE "GHI\n";                     # [21] Raises a FATAL warning
                                                         # [22]
print "JKL";                                             # [23] Does not reach here (as expected)
```

However, shouldn't lines [09] and [18] also raise an error or a warning like the following since it is closed (unopened)?

- ERROR:  `print() on closed filehandle $outHandleA at printingToClosedHandle.pl line 9.`
- WARNING: `print() on unopened filehandle $outHandleA at printingToClosedHandle.pl line 9.`

This might be an issue with my version of Perl which is "perl 5, version 28, subversion 1 (v5.28.1) built for MSWin32-x64-multi-thread". Furthermore, here is the output of the program I get below:

| outputA.txt | outputB.txt | STDOUT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| FILE A | FILE B | GLOB(0xfeb428)GLOB(0xfeb428)----- |

The STDOUT output in above table is from lines [08], [10], and [11]. Please note that the value between the parenthesis (...) in the above table might change with each execution.

Comment: You might be interested in the `autodie` pragma instead of trying to make warnings errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a difference between a filehandle that has been opened (initialized) and got closed, and one that has not been opened at all; attempting to print to them draws different warnings. One of ['unopened' entries in perldiag](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag#%25s()-on-unopened-%25s) says

> **%s() on unopened %s**
> (W unopened) An I/O operation was attempted on a filehandle that was never initialized. You need to do an open(), a sysopen(), or a socket() call, or call a constructor from the FileHandle package.

while an entry for [print() on closed filehandle](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag#print()-on-closed-filehandle-%25s) says

> **print() on closed filehandle %s**
> (W closed) The filehandle you're printing on got itself closed sometime before now. Check your control flow.

They both get the warnings though.

When `use warnings FATAL => 'unopened'` alone is enabled then printing to a filehandle that had been initialized but then closed does not get a warning.

```
use warnings;
#use warnings FATAL => 'unopened';
use strict;
use feature 'say';

open my $stdout, '>&', *STDOUT;    # a copy

say $stdout "hi";
close $stdout;
say $stdout "to lexical, closed";  # it warns (l.10)

FATAL_warnings_unopened: { 
    no warnings;                   # change to FATAL for 'unopened'
    use warnings FATAL => 'unopened';

    say $stdout "with FATAL to closed fh";      # no warning
    close STDOUT;
    say "with FATAL to STDOUT";                 # no warning

    say NON_EXISTENT_FH "no such filehandle!";  # l.20
};

say STDERR 'done';
```

This prints

```
hi
say() on closed filehandle $stdout at warnings_FATAL.pl line 10.
say() on unopened filehandle NON_EXISTENT_FH at warnings_FATAL.pl line 20.
```

It does exit, per FATAL and an `unopened` filehandle `NON_EXISTENT_FH` inside the block, but there is no warnings for the print to `$stdout` right above it.  There is a warning for the first such print. A print to `STDOUT` which just got closed doesn't get a warning either.

If we uncomment the `use warnings FATAL...` line in the very beginning (and remove other `warnings` lines) then no warnings are issued for printing to closed handles, at all.

A very close reading of the docs for the [warnings pragma](https://perldoc.perl.org/warnings) is helpful.  In short, I'd suggest to always first have `use warnings;` on its own, and then add a statement for categories wanted to be made `FATAL` (where multiple categories may be added in the same statement).

Comment: I understand now. If I do not want to turn all the warnings but warn me of unopened and already closed filehandle, then I should just call: ```use warnings FATAL => 'unopened';``` & ```use warnings FATAL => 'closed';```. As a note, **(l.10)** and **l.20** in your comments reflect line numbers that print to the console. Furthermore, when you say **(and remove other warnings lines)**, I assume you are referring to ```with_FATAL_warnings: { ... };```. As for ```>&```, I should take a look at [Duping filehandles](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open#Duping-filehandles) in Perldoc.

Comment: @MakotoWada Yes, to all points.  So we need to have `use warnings;` (always), and then can add those wanted to be fatal as well (and you can add a few in one statement, see docs for the warnings pragma, for which I am adding link at the very bottom of this answer).  As for "dup"-ing, some of the links in my other answer (on the question from which this one followed) are useful, I think.

Comment: Yes, regarding "dup"-ing, it is mentioned in [Perl's odd behavior when reassigning a filehandle variable from STDOUT to a file without undef()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66361138/perls-odd-behavior-when-reassigning-a-filehandle-variable-from-stdout-to-a-file#66363133) (the link which you refer to as "the links in my other answer (on the question from which this one followed))". Thanks.

Comment: @MakotoWada Right, that is what I meant.  This "dup"-ing (opening with `>&` mode) is a way to make a new, independent filehandle, which is a copy (to start with).  People commonly say "dup" because it uses `dup2` syscall (see `man 2 dup`) which duplicates a filehandle. I think that a useful example is in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57156978/4653379)  (linked in that answer), and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6417737/4653379) (from another link in that same answer) is particularly good, I think.

Answer (score 3):

You've run afoul of a detail of `use` and the importing mechanism behind it.  Namely, if you `use Foo 'bar';`, then *only* `Foo::bar` will be imported, even if `Foo` normally exports other things.

In the same way, `use warnings FATAL => 'unopened';` *does not* turn all warnings.  It turns on *only* 'unopened' warnings:

```
$ perl -E 'use warnings FATAL => "unopened" ; print $x;'
$ perl -E 'use warnings; use warnings FATAL => "unopened" ; print $x;'
Name "main::x" used only once: possible typo at -e line 1.
Use of uninitialized value $x in print at -e line 1.
```